# Find files in the order of timestamp

Tags: files, find, sort, timestamps

`dir` has two regular files.

`file1` has `abc\n`, `file2` has `def\n`. Compress these two files with gzip, as shown below,

```
#ls
#echo 'abc\n' > file1
#echo 'def\n' > file2
#gzip file1
#gzip file2
#ls
file1.gz  file2.gz
```

After I cat the content,

```
#find . -type f  -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -Iq . \{} \; -exec zcat \{} \;
def\n
abc\n
```

I do not get the content of files in order of the file creation time.
The expected output should be always `abc\ndef\n`.

Interesting observation: Actual output is sometime, `def\nabc\n` and sometimes `abc\ndef\n`

**Question:**

How to find files in order(decreasing/increasing) of timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to output the file timestamp along with the file path, sort by it, and then remove it:

```bash
find -type f -name "*.gz" -printf '%C@\t%p\n'|sort -nk1|cut -f2-|xargs zcat
```

Note that if your filenames can contain potentially unsafe characters (such as spaces), just replace

```
xargs zcat
```

with

```
xargs -d "\n" zcat
```

and if you need to accommodate for the newlines in the filenames,
you can use a null byte to terminate records, as detailed in @stéphane-chazelas answer (through that is rarely a problem in practice).

Comment: That assumes file names don't contain blanks, newline, quotes or backslashes. Note that `sort -nk1` is the same as `sort -n`.

Answer (score 3):

The order of files reported by `find` is opaque to the user. It can be the order they appear in the directory. Some `find` implementations reorder them by inode number or other criteria in an attempt to improve performance. The only way one may alter the order is via the `-depth` predicate that tells `find` to process/output leaves before the branch they're on.

As an alternative to `find`, you could use `zsh`'s recursive glob feature:

```
zgrep whatever ./**/*.gz(D.Om)
```

The `Om` glob qualifier is to sort by last-modification time (oldest first). `.` is for regular-files only (equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`), `D` is to include hidden (Dot) ones like `find` would by default.

If you get a *arg list too long* error, you can use `zargs`:

```
autoload -U zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs ./**/*.gz(D.Om) -- zgrep whatever
```

With `bash` (or any shell supporting Ksh-style process substitution) and recent GNU tools, an equivalent would be:

```
xargs -r0a <(
  export LC_ALL=C
  find . -type f -name '*.gz' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
    sort -zn | cut -zf2-) zgrep whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the find command works in such a way that the output is not guaranteed to be in alphabetical or file age time order. You might try something like:

```
ls -1dtr $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.gz') | xargs gzcat $1
```

Comment: That assumes file names don't contain blanks, newlines, quotes, backslashes or wildcards

Comment: This also assumes that the list of file names isn't too long to fit on a command line.